# Stripe Checkout - The payment type `three_d_secure` is currently not available

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout to collect customers' cards for future use (to create subscriptions).

```js
const { url } = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  mode: 'setup',
  customer: customer.data().stripe_customer, //customer id
  success_url: redirect,
  cancel_url: redirect,
});
```

However, most of the customers, especially in the US, are getting this error on Checkout: "The payment type `three_d_secure` is currently not available. Please try again later."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reach out to Stripe Support to get help on this. However, this error can happen when you have a Radar rule set to always require 3DS on payments. You will then get this error since most US card issuers don't support 3DS.

Comment: Already tried contacting them, but they're not sure about the cause.

Comment: Tried disabling Radar rules, same issue